# Negative sides of various git config options

Tags: git, performance, optimization, repository, config

I am hoping to optimize performance of hundreds of repositories, however I don't know the downsides to these config options.
I have learned there are upsides to:

1. Enable untracked-cache
   `git config core.untrackedcache true`
2. Enable FSMonitor:
   `git config core.fsmonitor true`
3. Repack git objects (run this occasionally)
   `git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250`
4. many files config optimization
   `git config feature.manyFiles true`

Are there any good reasons I should avoid setting these for all of my Repos? (they are not all large repos)

Comment: Side-note: You maybe also want run the garbage collector (`git gc`) periodically, if you don't do that automatically already. (See also: `gc.` params for `git config`)